# Specifying datatype at runtime using JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

I am using JOOQ to generate the SQL from the JAVA object. Below is my code-

```
String tableName = "tabel1";
String columnName = "column1";
String dataType = "varchar";

CreateTableAsStep<Record> createStmt = create.createTable(tableName).column(columnName, dataType);
```

It's not allowing to set the string datatype. But using SQLDatatype, I am getting only enumerated list of datatypes, which I have to supply at compile time only. Is it possible to set the datatype at runtime or any way to get the enumerated type using string name.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Uhm... JooQ allows you to create type safe `Field` instances...

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here might be what really happens at "runtime". If you have a variable in Java, such as:

```
DataType<?> dataType = SQLDataType.VARCHAR;
```

This doesn't mean that this value is set in stone. You can modify it dynamically *at runtime*, e.g. by letting the user choose from a dropdown what the data type really is. For instance, you could do something like:

```
Map<String, DataType<?>> choices = new LinkedHashMap<>();
choices.put("integer", SQLDataType.INTEGER);
choices.put("timestamp", SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP);
choices.put("varchar", SQLDataType.VARCHAR);
```

And then supply that to your jOOQ statement as such:

```
String tableName = "tabel1";
String columnName = "column1";
String dataType = "varchar";

create.createTable(tableName).column(columnName, choices.get(dataType))...;
```

Do remember that even if writing jOOQ statements feels like static SQL, it is really dynamic SQL. You are constructing a SQL statement via the jOOQ API dynamically at runtime. All elements involved with statement creation can be changed dynamically.

Comment: It will be helpful if we can have a method like SQLDatatype.valueOf(dataType), that returns the matched enumerated value for the supplied string datatype name.

Comment: There is internal API for that, but you shouldn't use it. The reason is: Will you provide the data type in upper case or lower case? With length, precision and scale, or without? A dialect-specific version or a standard version? The DDL type or the cast type?